# How do I correctly set the entry point for an exe in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++

I have set the entry point to WinMain but when I run the app it starts and doesn't display, I then have to shut it with task manager. Here's the code upto WinMain() :

```
#include <Windows.h>

// forward declarations
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam); 

// The entry point into a windows program
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int windowStyle )
{
....
```

I'm not experienced in C++, and I don't know what this is doing, except making my exe smaller, which is what I'm trying to achieve.

edit : What I'm trying to do is create a very small window exe to understand how demo coder's work. So I'm thinking of creating a small c++ window app that provides a window handle to which I can attach SlimDX (if i can statically link the final c++ dll to a C# app, but I'm not there yet) I have my BasicWindow.exe down to 6,656 bytes. So I'm experimenting with anything I can find to get that size down to <3k.

[2012.Jan.10] Well I've had some success by rebuilding minicrt (available from http://www.benshoof.org/blog/small-programs/) under VS2010 and adding it as an additional dependency. I couldn't Ignore All Default Libraries as suggested, but I now have a Windowed application with an exe size of 4,096 bytes. I'd say that's some significant success. I'm within striking distance now. Every reduction from here on in, is more room for SlimDX. I'm pretty happy considering the only c++ apps I've ever written are console apps and a basic window :) I've been lucky I know !

Comment: where do you set the entry point exactly?

Comment: Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > Advanced > Entry Point = WinMain

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A typical application should not mess up with `Entry point` setting of linker. Entry point should be set on a function included in the standard runtime library (which is `wWinMainCRTStartup` for unicode application for windows subsystem). This function does stuff like the proper initialization of CRT and creation of global objects. By rerouting entry point to your `WinMain` you will get undefined behavior unless you know precisely what you are doing and somehow implementing CRT initialization in your own `WinMain`. In my opinion the resulting size decrease will be negliable and the whole affair is hardly worth the risk.

Comment: You seem to be touching on the issues as discussed here www.benshoof.org/blog/small-programs/ Clearly I need to understand this subject to a much greater depth before expecting miracles with an entry point change. Perhaps employing something like minicrt is required to correctly change the entry point.

Comment: I would say the risk is not important, because this is a short experimental journey to understand how demo's work. But then, more than half the demo's Ive tried to view simply don't work on my computer, so that's the risk right there.

Comment: @GavinWilliams: I missed you edit while typing in my answer. Now I see the experimental nature of your approach. Oh well...  I guess you've answered your question yourself now, considering the link you've given :)

Comment: Gavin, if you change the entry point of your program, you need to make sure your new function has the same signature as the one you're replacing. The *real* entry point of the program is a zero-argument C function. Figure 3 of [Matt Pietrek's October 1996 "Under the Hood" article](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/archive/S569.aspx) shows how it prepares the arguments for `WinMain`.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've got some reading (and head-scratching) to do this morning.

Comment: I'd consider this question kinda answered, in that I've avoided redirecting the Entry Point and still achieved a 4096 byte exe size. A few other suggested link settings failed to work in my case, although they reduced the size of the exe even further (3,072 byte) but caused the app to stop. I'll have to return to this subject after more reading so that I can formulate more specific problems. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Gavin, I've brought down the size of the app for 64-bit build to 3072 bytes without losing any functionality and without any third-party library. Check my answer below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790923/how-do-i-correctly-set-the-entry-point-for-an-exe-in-visual-studio/27256649#27256649

Answer (score 2):

When you set the entry point to `WinMain`, Windows doesn't give your program a console window, because `WinMain` is for programs with GUIs that don't need a console window. Your program is indeed running, though with no GUI you don't see anything happen.

Comment: I don't understand, because this is a Win32 application, and i have created/registered a window. And called ShowWindow(). So my program doesn't need a console window, because it has a Win32 window. The window is shown correctly if i set no EntryPoint. Are you saying that all windows run in a console window ? And that the code that's being removed is what provides that console window ? And perhaps are you saying that Entry Points can't be changed for any applications using a window ?

Comment: @GavinWilliams set a breakpoint in the debugger on the first line of code in `WinMain` and run it in the debugger and see if the breakpoint is hit

Comment: No it's not hit, and VS shows that the app has terminated while task manager says that it's still running.

Comment: Sorry, Yes it is hit (I was running in release before). Stepping through the code, no window pops up at ShowWindow(hwnd, windowStyle), and the stepping marker gets lost at while ((status = GetMessage(&msg,(HWND) NULL,0,0)) != 0 && status != -1)

Comment: .. after going through it's body at least once { Translate(&msg); Dispatch(&msg)}. Could this indicate that my WindProc() is being lost because I'm skipping the forward declaration perhaps.

Comment: @GavinWilliams I don't think so. What what is the setting `Properties > Linker > System > SubSystem` set to?

Comment: The situation may be caused by a wrong value of `hInstance`. When you set WinMain as entry point you can not get your application instance handle from this argument anymore. Try getting `hInstance` from `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` and see what happens.

Comment: Using GetModuleHandle produces the same outcome, that the app runs but doesn't show the window. GetModuleHandle : zhInstance = 0x00b20000 {unused=9460301 } When i mouse-over hInstance in the WinMain parameter I see hInstance = 0x7efde000 {unused=134283264 }, I don't know if this conflicts with what your saying about it not being available. But also they are different values !

Comment: Ah !!! Pavel Zhuravlev, you hit the mark. It wasn't the hInstance, but the windowStyle int for ShowWindow that was being lost. So as soon as i put in SW_MAXIMIZE the window was visible. So with the Entry Point set to Winmain, my exe is now 3,584 bytes. That's a new personal best for 'Smallest C++ Window' :) I'm pretty sure I can shave off another 1k, but at some point I think I have to edit the files assembly, and get familiar with exe file structure. Also I haven't yet worked out how to adjust code/data alignment in the exe (if that's something I have to look into)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I wasn't satisfied with the [answer marked here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8791732/3418870). So, I started digging in more and found that WS_VISIBLE was missing from `CreateWindowEx` function.

`WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` with `WS_VISIBLE` makes the code work perfectly.

And regarding the file size, I was able to bring down the size of the code for x64 build to <del>3,072 bytes</del> **1,600 bytes** using **Visual Studio Community Edition 2013** running on Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 x64. All this, without using minicrt.lib, you mentioned above.

Here's a screenshot of the executable properties.

[image: Properties Window showing file size]

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here is the full program :

```
#include <Windows.h>

// forward declarations
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam); // WindowProcedure function

// The entry point into a windows program
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int  windowStyle )
{
// create and register a local window class > exit on failure
WNDCLASSEX wcx;
HINSTANCE zhInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
wcx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);                // size of structure
wcx.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;            // redraw if size changes
wcx.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;                      // window procedure
wcx.cbClsExtra = 0;                             // no extra class memory
wcx.cbWndExtra = 0;                             // no extra windows memory
wcx.hInstance = zhInstance;                     // handle to instance (owner)
wcx.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);    // predefined icon 
wcx.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);     // predefined arrow
wcx.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);//(HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW + 1);// white background brush
wcx.lpszMenuName = NULL;                        // name of menu resource
wcx.lpszClassName = TEXT("BasicWindow");        // name of window class
wcx.hIconSm = (HICON)LoadImage(zhInstance,              // small class icon 
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(5),
    IMAGE_ICON, 
    GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON), 
    GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON), 
    LR_DEFAULTCOLOR); 

if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcx))
{
    MessageBoxA(0, "Error registering window class!","Error",MB_ICONSTOP | MB_OK);
    DWORD result = GetLastError();
    return 0;
}

// create window > exit on failure
HWND hwnd; // the window handle
hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_STATICEDGE, 
    wcx.lpszClassName, 
    TEXT("Basic Window"), 
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    320,
    240,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    zhInstance,
    NULL);

if (hwnd == NULL)
{
    MessageBoxA(0,"Error creating window!","Error",MB_ICONSTOP | MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

// show window
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE);
// send a WM_PAINT message to the window
UpdateWindow(hwnd);

// enter message loop, break out of loop if there is an error (result = -1)
MSG msg;    // for storing the windows messages
int status; // for storing the status of the windows message service where -1 = error, 0 = WM_QUIT, n = any other message)
while ((status = GetMessage(&msg,(HWND) NULL,0,0)) != 0 && status != -1)
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

return msg.wParam;
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch(message)
{
case WM_CLOSE:
    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd,message,wParam,lParam);
}
return 0;
}
```