# VC11 Winsock Application Won't Shut Down

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, winsock2

I have an interesting scenario for a winsock app that seemingly will not close. The following is enough code to fully replicate the issue:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <WinSock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <MSTcpIP.h>
#include <ws2ipdef.h>

#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    WSAData wsaStartup;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaStartup);

    SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    addrinfo *result;
    addrinfo hint = { 0 };
    hint.ai_family = AF_INET6;

    int error = getaddrinfo("localhost", "45000", &hint, &result);

    if (error || !result) {
        cout << "Unable to resolve host. " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    error = connect(s, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen);

    if (error == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cout << "Unable to connect to host. " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Connection successful." << endl;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);
    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

I have spent numerous hours trying to track the issue down. It seems like getaddrinfo and connect both spawn an nt thread that hangs out, and prevents the app from terminating.

The only important compiler option that I changed here is: Linker->Advanced->EntryPoint where I specified "main". If I get rid of that compiler option, and change the main signature to:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
```

everything seems to work fine. In my use case, I am fine having the above _tmain function, but I am wondering if anyone has any idea what magic is going on behind the scenes of the _tmain function that is making the app close.

Comment: No, I have the server code running in a separate process. I suppose I didn't explain that well enough, but execution leaves the scope of the main method, so the main thread actually terminates. There are just 2 other threads that got spawned at the `getaddrinfo` call and the `connect` call that seem to be hanging out.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790923/how-do-i-correctly-set-the-entry-point-for-an-exe-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

[How do I correctly set the entry point for an exe in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790923/how-do-i-correctly-set-the-entry-point-for-an-exe-in-visual-studio)

Perhaps you need to provide the correct signature for main() to match what the runtime is expecting.

Comment: I was hoping for something more specific about the winsock api. I know how to fix the problem (go back to the ms specific main function), but I wanted to know why the standard convention was causing problems.